# calling CORS API using java script and proxy.php what could be the error in Code?

Tags: javascript, php, html

java script code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
table,th,td {
  border : 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,td {
  padding: 5px;
}
</style>
<body>

<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Show Details</button>
<br><br>
<table id="demo"></table>

<script>

function loadXMLDoc() {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     // xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; //
      myFunction(this);
    }
  };

  xmlhttp.open("GET", "proxy.php?a=pjm", true);
  //https://crossorigin.me/
  //&callback=? 

  //xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://db1.SITENAME.com:8080/WEB_API/awb_ref_query.asmx/awb_ref_query_xml?str_awb_refno=160230230&str_awb_refno_type=AWB&str_userid=testapi&str_pwd=testapi", true);
  alert("zero");


  xmlhttp.send();

}
function myFunction(xml) {
  var i;
  alert("first");

 var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  alert("second");
  var table="<tr><th>Progress</th><th>Scan_Detail</th></tr>";
  alert("third");
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    alert(listLength());
});
   var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Scan_Detail");
  alert("fourth");

  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 

    table += "<tr><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("Progress")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("Delivered_Undelivered")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td></tr>";

  }
  alert("fifth");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
  alert("sixth");
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

proxy.php code

```
<?php
//set your return content type

header('Content-type: application/xml');
$c = $_GET['a'];

if($c=="pjm"){
    $url = 'http://db1.SITENAME.com:8080/WEB_API/awb_ref_query.asmx/awb_ref_query_xml?str_awb_refno=160230230&str_awb_refno_type=AWB&str_userid=testapi&str_pwd=testapi';

   // $url = 'https://www.w3schools.com/xml/guestbook.asp';
    }

    //get that website content
    $handle = fopen($url,"r");

    //if there is something read and return
    if($handle) {
        while(!feof($handle)) {
            $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);
            echo $buffer;
        }
        fclose($handle);

    }


?>
```

error is at 
'''var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Scan_Detail"); in html java script file

code suppose to show cross domain XML data file. What could be going wrong? using CORS chrome plugin and without using php java script this code works fine, but I have to run the java script code using php file and without using any plugin.
Early response is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: What are the exact error messages that the browser is logging in the devtools console?

Comment: why not use the `fetch` api - you can easily send cross-domain requests like this without the need for the intermediary `proxy.php` script

Comment: error is at '''var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Scan_Detail"); in html java script file @sideshowbarker

Comment: error is - error typeerror: cannot read property 'getelementsbytagname' of null @sideshowbarker

Answer (score 0):

Rather than complicating matters with the `proxy` script you can use the `Fetch` api and instruct it to perform a `CORS` request directly - the `Fetch` api is very easy to use too which is a bonus.

When you look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) it might seem a little daunting if you are familiar with the simplicity of XMLHttpRequest calls but it is worth it as the whole `Promise` based methodology is the way forward.

This code worked for a known url but cannot be tested for your endpoint...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Fetch & Parse XML</title>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
                const url='http://db1.SITENAME.com:8080/WEB_API/awb_ref_query.asmx/awb_ref_query_xml?str_awb_refno=160230230&str_awb_refno_type=AWB&str_userid=testapi&str_pwd=testapi';

                const config={
                    mode:'cors',
                    credentials:'omit',
                    cache:'default',
                    redirect:'follow'
                };

                const callback=function(r){
                    let oParser=new DOMParser();
                    let data=oParser.parseFromString( r, 'text/xml' );

                    /* do something with the parsed XML document... */
                    console.info( data );
                };


                fetch( url, config ).then( response => {
                    return response.text();
                }).then( xml => {
                    callback( xml )
                }).catch( error => {
                    alert( error )
                })
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- content -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the immediate response. I'll check and let you know. @RamRaider

Comment: I used const url='https://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml'; It gives TypeError: Failed to fetch. Please guide. Thanks @RamRaider

Comment: If you load that page in your browser but look at the console ( specifically at the Network request ) and look at the `response` header you will notice there is no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header... without this cross-domain requests using javascript will not work. Your question referred to a `CORS api` so that suggests the particular endpoint is available to a CORS request as with `fetch`.

Comment: If the remote site does not set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to `*` ( all ) then XMLHttpRequest & Fetch will not work - in such a case your `proxy` idea is probably the way to go but use `curl` with suitable options set for the endpoint ( ie: ssl, cookies, useragent etc )

Comment: You can try setting the `mode` option in the config from `cors` to `no-cors` to access that XML file

Comment: Can anyone figure out what would be the error in php code? Thanks

Comment: Can you confirm that the actual url is http and not https? `fopen` for remote urls often fails - check that `allow_url_fopen` is enabled

Comment: Thanks for the guiding!  1. actual url is http 2.  the xml database is on godady and accessing by sql server from pc.  (godady might have allow_url_fopen settings). 3. We are accessing xml file from another c-panel (another hosing provider.) If any other I'll know I'll share you. Thanks

Comment: I have added https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ prefix to my url in js code and now it is working without headers and php. I don't know for how long it will work.  @RamRaider Thanks you for your kind co-operation.